# what does "xx free bytes and xx until OOM" mean?

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I got such an exception in my Android app`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 32 byte allocation with 0 free bytes and 3GB until OOM`. What does 0 free bytes mean? and 3GB?

Comment: You should provide the code around the error.

Comment: @KyleK I know it is OOM but not sure why there is 0 free bytes and what 3GB mea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0 free bytes means exactly what is says. The bit I didn't understand was `3GB until next OOM`

I rooted through the Android source and here's where you see this error (in some random version of Android, I'm not sure which)

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/dd162fb5990cedf80a5093ecc0e77df82af5f754/runtime/gc/heap.cc#872

```
 oss << "Failed to allocate a " << byte_count << " byte allocation with " << 
 total_bytes_free
 << " free bytes and " << PrettySize(GetFreeMemoryUntilOOME()) << " until OOM";
```

3GB is the `GetFreeMemoryUntilOOME` function which appears to be this:

```
// Returns approximately how much free memory we have until the next OOME happens.
size_t GetFreeMemoryUntilOOME() const {
  return growth_limit_ - GetBytesAllocated();
}
```

I'm not sure on what growth_limit is, but I'm pretty from reading that's it's the maximum heap size?

This is a terrible answer really with me guessing from the Android source but there's nothing else here so I'll post it!